# How to solve my skin showing in my walk animation?

Tags: modeling, animation

[image]

How do I fix this in blender 2.8? I tried parenting it with empty group and automatic weights.

Answer (score 2):

You could remove this part of your mesh, but you could also use the *Mask* modifier:

- Select the part of the skin mesh you want to make invisible, create a vertex group.
- Give your skin object a *Mask* modifier, select the group.
- Invert the selection with the double arrows button.
- Now this part of your mesh is invisible.

[image]

For more complexe meshes you should check out the *Mesh Deform* modifier method: create a cage around the clothes, give your clothes a *Mesh Deform* modifier with this cage as *Target*, and instead of parenting the clothes to the armature, parent the cage...